# geom_text not annotating chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a small annotation to a chart in ggplot, but geom_text doesn't seem to be displaying properly. Ideally, I'd like to add the annotation at x = 10, y = 1000, but it doesn't seem to be cooperating. Has anyone had experience with something like this

Chart

[image: Chart in question]

Code used to make it.

```
                                                          y = as.numeric(CD8.Density.Tumor.mm))) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10',  expand = c(0,0), limits = c(1, 8000),
                     labels = prettyNum) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',  expand = c(0,0), limits = c(1, 4000),
                     labels = prettyNum) +
  # RECTANGLES OF BINS----------------------------------------------------------
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0, xmax=stroma_cutoff, ymin=0, ymax = epi_cutoff),
          alpha = 0.01, fill = "lightblue2") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=stroma_cutoff, xmax=8000, ymin=0, ymax = epi_cutoff),
            alpha = 0.01, fill = "khaki1") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0, xmax=8000, ymin=epi_cutoff, ymax = 4000),
            alpha = 0.03, fill = "rosybrown1") +
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  geom_point(aes(color = Pathologist.Phenotype,
               fill = Pathologist.Phenotype,
               shape = Indication),
           size = 1,
           stroke = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23,24,25)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue",
                              "orange",
                              "red")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue",
                             "orange",
                             "red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  geom_text(x = 10,
            y = 1000,
            label = "Pancreatic")
```

And dataframe in dput format.

```
structure(list(ID = c("KY390", "LC686", "LE496", "LH400", "LY701", 
"MF985", "MO370", "MT774", "MV192", "MY275", "NA850", "NC532", 
"ND177", "NI460", "NI853", "NM459", "NO436", "NR211", "NS701", 
"OA874", "15H5131", "19H12892", "LF014", "LT433", "LV504", "LV676", 
"MA065", "MH024", "MI506", "ML585", "ML716", "ML778", "MP960", 
"NA759", "NC966", "NP186", "JO618", "JQ480", "JS182", "JS20", 
"JS244", "JT68", "KB784", "KB834", "KC647", "KP860", "KU43", 
"KX782", "LQ377", "LU095", "LV399", "LY363", "ME681", "MT838", 
"NK521", "NL792", "JP755", "JX936", "KC630", "KU71", "LD239", 
"LS068", "LS197", "LZ860", "MJ245", "ML175", "MM528", "MV097", 
"MX356", "MY147", "MY278", "ND945", "NF975", "LK423", "LO514", 
"LQ219", "LS028", "LS601", "LU466", "LZ953", "MA239", "MB864", 
"MG940", "MK566", "MR948", "MU763", "NC030", "ND323", "ND559", 
"NE902", "NF884", "NR516", "NV525"), Pathologist.Phenotype = c("Excluded", 
"Desert", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", 
"Desert", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Desert", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", 
"Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Desert", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", 
"Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", 
"Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", 
"Excluded", "Desert"), IA.Phenotype = c("Excluded", "Desert", 
"Desert", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
"Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", 
"Desert", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
"Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Desert", 
"Desert", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Desert", "Excluded", "Desert", 
"Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Infiltrated", 
"Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Desert", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
"Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Desert", "Desert", "Infiltrated", 
"Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Desert", 
"Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
"Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded"), 
    Indication = c("Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", 
    "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", 
    "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", 
    "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "Colorectal", 
    "Colorectal", "Colorectal", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", 
    "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", 
    "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", 
    "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", 
    "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", 
    "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", "Ovarian", 
    "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", 
    "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", 
    "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", 
    "Pancreatic", "Pancreatic", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", 
    "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", 
    "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "TNBC"
    ), CD45.Count.Tumor = c(3967L, 48L, 340L, 18433L, 5169L, 
    1073L, 147L, 5278L, 4378L, 7088L, 1662L, 2052L, 5334L, 1867L, 
    10398L, 15162L, 1520L, 133L, 480L, 4810L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 239L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 9159L, 3557L, 9564L, 25885L, 294L, 16501L, 4323L, 
    82L, 784L, 14026L, 512L, 4574L, 1470L, 3085L, 2244L, 640L, 
    419L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3548L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CD8.Count.Tumor = c(1507L, 
    6L, 275L, 19962L, 688L, 288L, 370L, 1722L, 2909L, 1696L, 
    2588L, 1977L, 1368L, 1766L, 8619L, 9741L, 4549L, 114L, 133L, 
    1284L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 182L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3865L, 1932L, 1465L, 3358L, 
    18L, 1439L, 372L, 105L, 41L, 7419L, 143L, 435L, 97L, 1246L, 
    599L, 67L, 115L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 241L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Area.Tumor = c(84360668.55, 
    1632458.56, 42004746.7, 77489279.3, 71908150.81, 25337906.87, 
    13647066.54, 24246320.88, 40745593.14, 150573599.2, 39888720.75, 
    107409091.1, 78609623.29, 50254005.88, 77436494.65, 66408519.53, 
    84618718.78, 11631821.73, 17247513.69, 35927496.83, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23123356.67, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40155359.97, 25844194.94, 10213686.7, 
    27007444.95, 75085.5, 45972231.72, 13809348.33, 244872.69, 
    2664622.03, 37124798.19, 3910049.77, 8495677.38, 11367062.81, 
    18918016.25, 3845582.82, 277382.05, 2164153.87, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14784764.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CD45.Density.Tumor = c(4.7e-05, 2.94e-05, 
    8.09e-06, 0.000237878, 7.19e-05, 4.23e-05, 1.08e-05, 0.000217683, 
    0.000107447, 4.71e-05, 4.17e-05, 1.91e-05, 6.79e-05, 3.72e-05, 
    0.000134278, 0.000228314, 1.8e-05, 1.14e-05, 2.78e-05, 0.000133881, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.03e-05, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.000228089, 0.000137632, 0.000936391, 
    0.000958439, 0.003915536, 0.000358934, 0.000313049, 0.000334868, 
    0.000294226, 0.000377807, 0.000130945, 0.000538391, 0.000129321, 
    0.000163072, 0.000583527, 0.002307287, 0.000193609, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.000239977, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CD8.Density.Tumor = c(1.79e-05, 
    3.68e-06, 6.55e-06, 0.00025761, 9.57e-06, 1.14e-05, 2.71e-05, 
    7.1e-05, 7.14e-05, 1.13e-05, 6.49e-05, 1.84e-05, 1.74e-05, 
    3.51e-05, 0.000111304, 0.000146683, 5.38e-05, 9.8e-06, 7.71e-06, 
    3.57e-05, 7.62e-05, 0.000562221, 8.94e-06, 4.75e-05, 3.78e-05, 
    2.68e-05, 0.000111762, 0.000114708, 0.000246036, 3.49e-05, 
    0.000111372, 0.000645046, 0.00012735, 0.000110988, 0.000287598, 
    7.18e-05, 1.19e-05, 0.000158808, 8.49e-05, 3.22e-05, 0.000163758, 
    7.56e-05, 1.66e-05, 5.48e-05, 4.31e-05, 0.000184835, 0.000148136, 
    0.000240584, 1.79e-05, 7.87e-06, 0.000159397, 5.74e-05, 1.11e-05, 
    2.84e-05, 0.000184465, 0.000881192, 9.63e-05, 7.48e-05, 0.000143435, 
    0.000124336, 0.000239727, 3.13e-05, 2.69e-05, 0.000428794, 
    1.54e-05, 0.000199839, 3.66e-05, 5.12e-05, 8.53e-06, 6.59e-05, 
    0.000155763, 0.000241544, 5.31e-05, 9.36e-05, 0.000121794, 
    6.27e-06, 5.3e-05, 0.000261309, 1.48e-05, 0.00024795, 1.25e-05, 
    0.000170372, 1.63e-05, 0.002985673, 0.000135752, 5.29e-05, 
    1.17e-05, 6.82e-05, 0.000204643, 4.48e-05, 1.91e-05, 4.7e-05, 
    1.64e-05), CD8.Density.Tumor.mm = c(17.8638, 3.67544, 6.54688, 
    257.61, 9.56776, 11.3664, 27.1121, 71.0211, 71.3942, 11.2636, 
    64.8805, 18.4063, 17.4024, 35.1415, 111.304, 146.683, 53.7588, 
    9.8007, 7.71126, 35.7386, 76.2060107, 562.2205484, 8.93501879, 
    47.47623684, 37.84388979, 26.77161203, 111.7621886, 114.7080098, 
    246.0362408, 34.85604794, 111.3715051, 645.0461176, 127.3498083, 
    110.9878319, 287.5976602, 71.78016328, 11.93877884, 158.8075009, 
    84.92250258, 32.17279188, 163.758254, 75.56527532, 16.59936, 
    54.78228723, 43.06401936, 184.8346915, 148.1358017, 240.5836398, 
    17.91082973, 7.87082959, 159.3966958, 57.38430704, 11.12491558, 
    28.35563449, 184.464868, 881.1915933, 96.25116056, 74.75566581, 
    143.4349851, 124.3360861, 239.7267115, 31.30150411, 26.93827334, 
    428.7942441, 15.38679765, 199.8394702, 36.5724245, 51.20250929, 
    8.53342694, 65.8631425, 155.7631257, 241.5441086, 53.13855063, 
    93.60446779, 121.7941411, 6.2694926, 53.00489028, 261.3088799, 
    14.82462488, 247.94963, 12.45675785, 170.3716321, 16.30056346, 
    2985.673004, 135.7517982, 52.92997266, 11.67254633, 68.20921325, 
    204.6427063, 44.77298116, 19.06148601, 46.9768258, 16.35480876
    ), CD8.Density.Tumor.test = c(17.8638, 3.67544, 6.54688, 
    257.61, 9.56776, 11.3664, 27.1121, 71.0211, 71.3942, 11.2636, 
    64.8805, 18.4063, 17.4024, 35.1415, 111.304, 146.683, 53.7588, 
    9.8007, 7.71126, 35.7386, 76.2060107, 562.2205484, 8.93501879, 
    47.47623684, 37.84388979, 26.77161203, 111.7621886, 114.7080098, 
    246.0362408, 34.85604794, 111.3715051, 645.0461176, 127.3498083, 
    110.9878319, 287.5976602, 71.78016328, 11.93877884, 158.8075009, 
    84.92250258, 32.17279188, 163.758254, 75.56527532, 16.59936, 
    54.78228723, 43.06401936, 184.8346915, 148.1358017, 240.5836398, 
    17.91082973, 7.870829594, 159.3966958, 57.38430704, 11.12491558, 
    28.35563449, 184.464868, 881.1915933, 96.25116056, 74.75566581, 
    143.4349851, 124.3360861, 239.7267115, 31.30150411, 26.93827334, 
    428.7942441, 15.38679765, 199.8394702, 36.5724245, 51.20250929, 
    8.53342694, 65.8631425, 155.7631257, 241.5441086, 53.13855063, 
    93.60446779, 121.7941411, 6.2694926, 53.00489028, 261.3088799, 
    14.82462488, 247.94963, 12.45675785, 170.3716321, 16.30056346, 
    2985.673004, 135.7517982, 52.92997266, 11.67254633, 68.20921325, 
    204.6427063, 44.77298116, 19.06148601, 46.9768258, 16.35480876
    ), CD45.Count.Stroma = c(186295L, 10014L, 34887L, 41774L, 
    119768L, 47290L, 35148L, 57075L, 87161L, 47189L, 17103L, 
    76919L, 82982L, 31192L, 78126L, 62031L, 13784L, 6648L, 6718L, 
    28039L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 27930L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29395L, 7806L, 47395L, 
    51722L, 1580L, 76205L, 16241L, 518L, 655L, 16081L, 5095L, 
    24425L, 16485L, 8539L, 25869L, 3411L, 790L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 110637L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), CD8.Count.Stroma = c(32799L, 1211L, 20982L, 
    26338L, 20662L, 10525L, 20949L, 28686L, 42138L, 12746L, 10097L, 
    40005L, 14577L, 11807L, 27638L, 27877L, 24697L, 1710L, 2506L, 
    4261L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 8378L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23157L, 8362L, 21995L, 
    16415L, 781L, 10543L, 2475L, 1161L, 88L, 11284L, 5411L, 5837L, 
    2954L, 3161L, 9985L, 752L, 266L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4488L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), Area.Stroma = c(106467238.6, 16606875.98, 45720311.66, 
    35840492.52, 45095448.88, 48250440.05, 79024239.78, 61153450.81, 
    55242411.82, 55952933.86, 14071538.44, 78007501.27, 31632366.77, 
    34352533.86, 133949500.4, 61790313.46, 36806350.38, 18047911.69, 
    11422073.44, 13576324.29, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44396955.26, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 62841609.25, 74623233.88, 191758172.8, 163723363, 1135766.02, 
    167030450.4, 35804066.74, 3439640.3, 2020700.41, 26648098.89, 
    35730513.02, 63897465.64, 91758678.94, 51173183.98, 21544994.74, 
    1071918.95, 2100429.14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    53078495.54, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CD45.Density.Stroma = c(0.001749787, 
    0.000603003, 0.000763053, 0.001165553, 0.002655878, 0.000980095, 
    0.000444775, 0.000933308, 0.001577791, 0.00084337, 0.001215432, 
    0.000986046, 0.002623326, 0.000907997, 0.00058325, 0.001003895, 
    0.000374501, 0.000368353, 0.000588159, 0.002065287, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.000629097, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.000467763, 0.000104605, 0.00024716, 
    0.000315911, 0.001391132, 0.000456234, 0.000453608, 0.000150597, 
    0.000324145, 0.000603458, 0.000142595, 0.000382253, 0.000179656, 
    0.000166865, 0.001200697, 0.003182144, 0.000376114, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.002084403, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CD8.Density.Stroma = c(0.000308067, 
    7.29e-05, 0.000458921, 0.000734867, 0.000458184, 0.000218133, 
    0.000265096, 0.000469082, 0.000762783, 0.000227799, 0.000717548, 
    0.000512835, 0.000460825, 0.000343701, 0.000206331, 0.000451155, 
    0.000670998, 9.47e-05, 0.0002194, 0.000313855, 0.000605314, 
    0.000409513, 4.8e-05, 0.000125563, 6.79e-05, 0.000165575, 
    0.000205282, 0.000261293, 0.000636891, 5.67e-05, 0.00015328, 
    0.000578501, 0.000498693, 0.000356713, 0.00057618, 0.000289819, 
    3.6e-05, 0.000179223, 0.000176623, 7.22e-05, 0.000835928, 
    0.000190605, 0.000124018, 0.000208898, 7.87e-05, 0.000904639, 
    0.000233836, 0.000556059, 0.000180125, 0.000188707, 0.000238821, 
    0.000460909, 0.000344729, 0.000196725, 0.000629671, 0.000893557, 
    0.000368498, 0.000112056, 0.000114702, 0.000100261, 0.000687642, 
    6.31e-05, 6.91e-05, 0.000337535, 4.35e-05, 0.000423445, 0.000151439, 
    9.13e-05, 3.22e-05, 6.18e-05, 0.000463449, 0.000701546, 0.000126641, 
    0.001078743, 0.000343645, 4.79e-05, 9.16e-05, 0.000385962, 
    0.000210725, 0.000570611, 0.000222117, 0.000865005, 8.46e-05, 
    0.002070285, 0.000237429, 0.000185117, 0.000199765, 0.00060757, 
    0.000216349, 0.000199593, 9.61e-05, 0.000322258, 0.000188101
    ), CD8.Density.Stroma.mm = c(308.067, 72.9216, 458.921, 734.867, 
    458.184, 218.133, 265.096, 469.082, 762.783, 227.799, 717.548, 
    512.835, 460.825, 343.701, 206.331, 451.155, 670.998, 94.7478, 
    219.4, 313.855, 605.3140521, 409.5132753, 48.0131514, 125.5633667, 
    67.88235552, 165.5751584, 205.2816242, 261.2929654, 636.8906929, 
    56.6840978, 153.2797991, 578.5008979, 498.6927778, 356.7130637, 
    576.1801072, 289.8191731, 35.98427614, 179.2233229, 176.623269, 
    72.16843305, 835.9284834, 190.6045575, 124.0176237, 208.8978813, 
    78.73842752, 904.6388451, 233.8355424, 556.059479, 180.1246715, 
    188.7066343, 238.8210389, 460.9087923, 344.7286036, 196.7246175, 
    629.6710601, 893.5572236, 368.4978834, 112.0562533, 114.7017605, 
    100.2605841, 687.6416324, 63.12022731, 69.12622574, 337.535294, 
    43.54925627, 423.4448411, 151.4391914, 91.34947594, 32.19314003, 
    61.77063364, 463.4487091, 701.5455786, 126.6407873, 1078.743327, 
    343.6448377, 47.85460607, 91.59677042, 385.9624399, 210.7246487, 
    570.6114827, 222.1166624, 865.0052834, 84.55401673, 2070.284854, 
    237.4290068, 185.1165225, 199.7648854, 607.5696492, 216.3494329, 
    199.5928585, 96.11777003, 322.2578632, 188.1012078), CD8.Density.Stroma.test = c(308.067, 
    72.9216, 458.921, 734.867, 458.184, 218.133, 265.096, 469.082, 
    762.783, 227.799, 717.548, 512.835, 460.825, 343.701, 206.331, 
    451.155, 670.998, 94.7478, 219.4, 313.855, 605.3140521, 409.5132753, 
    48.0131514, 125.5633667, 67.88235552, 165.5751584, 205.2816242, 
    261.2929654, 636.8906929, 56.6840978, 153.2797991, 578.5008979, 
    498.6927778, 356.7130637, 576.1801072, 289.8191731, 35.98427614, 
    179.2233229, 176.623269, 72.16843305, 835.9284834, 190.6045575, 
    124.0176237, 208.8978813, 78.73842752, 904.6388451, 233.8355424, 
    556.059479, 180.1246715, 188.7066343, 238.8210389, 460.9087923, 
    344.7286036, 196.7246175, 629.6710601, 893.5572236, 368.4978834, 
    112.0562533, 114.7017605, 100.2605841, 687.6416324, 63.12022731, 
    69.12622574, 337.535294, 43.54925627, 423.4448411, 151.4391914, 
    91.34947594, 32.19314003, 61.77063364, 463.4487091, 701.5455786, 
    126.6407873, 1078.743327, 343.6448377, 47.85460607, 91.59677042, 
    385.9624399, 210.7246487, 570.6114827, 222.1166624, 865.0052834, 
    84.55401673, 2070.284854, 237.4290068, 185.1165225, 199.7648854, 
    607.5696492, 216.3494329, 199.5928585, 96.11777003, 322.2578632, 
    188.1012078), IA.Cutoff.Phenotype = c("Excluded", "Desert", 
    "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
    "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
    "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
    "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", 
    "Desert", "Desert", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
    "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", 
    "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Infiltrated", 
    "Excluded", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", 
    "Excluded", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", 
    "Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Excluded", 
    "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", 
    "Desert", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Desert", "Infiltrated", 
    "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Desert", "Desert", 
    "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Excluded", 
    "Excluded", "Desert", "Desert", "Infiltrated", "Excluded", 
    "Infiltrated", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", "Desert", "Infiltrated", 
    "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Excluded", "Infiltrated", 
    "Excluded", "Desert", "Excluded", "Excluded")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 66L, 67L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 
91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
103L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `annotate('text', x = 10, y = 1000, label = 'Pancreatic')` instead of `geom_text`